# pad matrix with zeroes to achieve desired shape in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matrix

Hi I have a `19 x 3` matrix, however I want to make it `513 x 3` matrix.
So i just need to maintain my 19  rows and the remaining zeroes or ones to make up 513
is this possible?

Comment: First of all create 513 x 3 matrix with zero elements and then copy 19 x 3 matrix to your new matrix.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use `append` on `axis=0`:

```
arr2 = np.zeros((513-19, 3))
new_arr = np.append(arr1, arr2, axis=0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `numpy.pad()`

In your case, if you want your 19x3 values in the center of the matrix, you should use:

```
import numpy as np
padded_matrix = np.pad(your_matrix, ((247, 247), (0, 0)))
```

`247` comes from `(513-19)/2`

EDIT: If instead, you want to keep the values in the first 19 rows and pad the matrix at the bottom, change the parameters:

```
padded_matrix = np.pad(your_matrix, ((0, 513-19), (0, 0)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this (check [[NumPy]: Assigning values to indexed arrays](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#assigning-values-to-indexed-arrays) and [[NumPy]: Broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) for more details):

> ```py
> >>>
> >>> import numpy as np
> >>>
> >>>
> >>> rows_inner, cols_inner = 19, 3
> >>> rows_outer, cols_outer = 513, 3
> >>>
> >>> inner = np.arange(rows_inner * cols_inner).reshape(rows_inner, cols_inner)
> >>> inner.shape, inner.dtype
> ((19, 3), dtype('int32'))
> >>> inner
> array([[ 0,  1,  2],
>        [ 3,  4,  5],
>        [ 6,  7,  8],
>        [ 9, 10, 11],
>        [12, 13, 14],
>        [15, 16, 17],
>        [18, 19, 20],
>        [21, 22, 23],
>        [24, 25, 26],
>        [27, 28, 29],
>        [30, 31, 32],
>        [33, 34, 35],
>        [36, 37, 38],
>        [39, 40, 41],
>        [42, 43, 44],
>        [45, 46, 47],
>        [48, 49, 50],
>        [51, 52, 53],
>        [54, 55, 56]])
> >>>
> >>>
> >>> outer = np.zeros((rows_outer, cols_outer), dtype=np.int32)
> >>> outer.shape, outer.dtype
> ((513, 3), dtype('int32'))
> >>> outer
> array([[0, 0, 0],
>        [0, 0, 0],
>        [0, 0, 0],
>        ...,
>        [0, 0, 0],
>        [0, 0, 0],
>        [0, 0, 0]])
> >>>
> >>>
> >>> outer[0:rows_inner,:] = inner  # !!! Simple Assignment !!!
> >>>
> >>> outer.shape, outer.dtype
> ((513, 3), dtype('int32'))
> >>> outer
> array([[0, 1, 2],
>        [3, 4, 5],
>        [6, 7, 8],
>        ...,
>        [0, 0, 0],
>        [0, 0, 0],
>        [0, 0, 0]])
> ```